# Converting Rows To Columns With Unknown Number Of Elements

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to achive this:

Initial table:

```
PARM1 |PARM2 |DATE
-------------------
VALUE1|VALUE2|DATE1

VALUE3|VALUE4|DATE2
```

Final result:

```
PARM |DATE1 |DATE2 |...
-----------------------
PARM1|VALUE1|VALUE3|...

PARM2|VALUE2|VALUE4|...
```

Briefly, I want to convert my parameter names into lines and to have a column for every date, where the cells contain the parameter values for the date and parameter.

So far, I managed to get this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT [Parameter], [DATE], VALUE
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT PARM1, PARM2 FROM PARAMETER_VALUES
    ) SOURCE_TABLE
    UNPIVOT
    (
        VALOR FOR [Parameter] IN (PARM1, PARM2)
    ) UNPIVOTED_TABLE
) T
```

The problem is, I can't PIVOT the results now, because I don't know how many DATEs there are. I want it to be dynamic.

Is it possible?

Comment: Sounds like an EAV structure which has come to bite you in the behind. Fundamentally, databases are not designed to dynamically generate columns. So, if that is what you want to do, you should do it outside the database in a middle-tier component or reporting tool.

Comment: If you post code, XML or fixed table structures, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't use the `PIVOT` command with unknown columns.

Your only option is to retrieve the data and reformat, using dynamic SQL or some kind of front end.

Answer (score 0):

You can pivot using dynamic columns, if you build the pivot before hand.

```
SELECT  @listColYouwantInPivot= STUFF(( SELECT distinct  '], [' + [columnName]
                           FROM     tableName
                         FOR
                           XML PATH('')
                         ), 1, 2, '') + ']'
```

Just plug @listColYouwantInPivot in the pivot statement with a concatenation afterward.